# Are these two definitions of $\mathcal{U}$-Ramsey set equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, ultrafilters, ramsey-theory

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an ultrafilter over $\omega$, and let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$. In two separate texts, there are two possible interpretations of a $\mathcal{U}$-Ramsey set, as described below (Definition 7.37 and Definition 3). My question is:

> Do these two definitions coincide? What if we restrict $\mathcal{U}$ to be a Ramsey ultrafilter?

---

**Interpretation 1.** The first interpretation is found in Stevo Todorcevic's book *Introduction to Ramsey Spaces*.

**Definition 7.29.** For any ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ over $\omega$ (not necessarily Ramsey), we define a **$\mathcal{U}$-tree** to be a subtree $T$ of ${}^{<\omega}\omega$ (finite subsets of $\omega$, not sequences) with the property that for every finite subset $t \subseteq \omega$ such that $\operatorname{stem}(T) \subseteq t$, we have:
$$
\{n \in \omega : t \cup \{n\} \in T\} \in \mathcal{U}
$$
**Definition 7.30.** For two $\mathcal{U}$-trees $T'$ and $T$, we say that $T'$ is a **pure refinement** of $T$ if $\operatorname{stem}(T') = \operatorname{stem}(T)$ and $T' \subseteq T$.

**Definition 7.37.** We then say that $\mathcal{X}$ is **$\mathcal{U}$-Ramsey** if for every $\mathcal{U}$-tree $T$, there is a pure refinement $T'$ of $T$ such that $[T'] \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ or $[T'] \subseteq \mathcal{X}^c$.

---

**Interpretation 2.** I first saw this interpretation in the paper [*Happy and mad families in $L(\mathbb{R})$*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ezbnorwood/files/hmlr.pdf), but I believe this is quite a standard definition.

**Definition 1.** If $y_0 \supseteq y_1 \supseteq y_2 \supseteq \cdots$ is a decreasing sequence of subsets of $\omega$, then we call a set $y_\infty \in [\omega]^\omega$  a **diagonalisation** of the sequence $\langle{y_n : n < \omega}\rangle$ iff $f(n+1) \in y_{f(n)}$ for every $n < \omega$, where $f : \omega \to \omega$ is the increasing enumeration of $y_\infty$.

**Definition 2.** A $\mathcal{H} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ is called a **coideal** if is satisfies the conditions:

1. (Upward-closure) If $x \in H$ and $y \supseteq x$, then $y \in H$.
2. (Pigeonhole) If $x_0 \cup \cdots \cup x_n \in H$, then $x_k \in H$ for some $k$.

Furthermore, $\mathcal{H}$ is said to be **selective** if it satisfies the condition:

3. (Selectivity) Every decreasing sequence $y_0 \supseteq y_1 \supseteq \cdots$ of members of $\mathcal{H}$ has a diagonalisation in $H$.

A selective coideal is also called a **happy family**.

**Definition 3.** If $H$ is a coideal (typically a happy family) and $\mathcal{X} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ is a set of reals, then we say $\mathcal{X}$ is **$\mathcal{H}$-Ramsey** if there is $M \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $[M]^\omega \subseteq X$ or $[M]^\omega \subseteq X^c$.

Note that if $\mathcal{H}$ is an ultrafilter, then it is a happy family iff it is a Ramsey ultrafilter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you ask if **Defintion 7.37.** and **Definition 3.** are equivalent for a Ramsey ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}(=\mathcal{H})$. The short answer is no, but let me elaborate.

Since for a $\mathcal{U}$-tree $T$, the set $[T]$ is technically a subset of $\omega^\omega$, we will only consider $\mathcal{U}$-trees $T$ such that $\text{stem}(T)$ is increasing. For such a tree $T$ there exists a pure refinement $T' \subseteq T$ such that every $x \in [T']$ is increasing, hence $\text{ran}(x) \in [\omega]^\omega$ can uniquely be identified with $x \in T'$.

**Fact:** If $\mathcal{U}$ is a Ramsey ultrafilter, then $\mathbb{M}_\mathcal{U}$ (Mathias forcing with an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$) is dense in $\mathbb{L}_\mathcal{U}$ (Laver forcing with an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ such that for every $T \in \mathbb{L}_\mathcal{U}$ we have that $\text{stem}(T)$ is increasing). In particular, for every $T \in \mathbb{L}_\mathcal{U}$ there exists $A \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\{\text{ran}(\text{stem}(T)) \cup x \,\, \colon \,\ x \in [A]^\omega \} \subseteq [T]$.

Now **Defintion 7.37.** obviously implies **Definition 3.** : Let $\mathcal{X} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ be arbitrary such that $\mathcal{X}$ is $\mathcal{U}$-Ramsey. Let $T$ be a pure refinement of $\omega^\omega$ such that either $[T] \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ or $[T] \cap \mathcal{X} = \emptyset$. By the above Fact we can find $A \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\{\emptyset \cup x \,\, \colon \,\ x \in [A]^\omega \} \subseteq [T]$. Hence $\mathcal{X}$ is also $\mathcal{H}$-Ramsey.

On the other hand **Definition 3.** does not imply **Defintion 7.37.** : By an induction of length $\mathfrak{c}$ we can construct a $\mathcal{X} \subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ which is not $\mathcal{H}$-Ramsey. W.l.o.g. we can assume $0 \notin x$ for every $x \in \mathcal{X}$. Now define $\mathcal{X}':=\{\{0\} \cup x \,\, \colon \,\, x \in \mathcal{X}\}$, which is obviously $\mathcal{H}$-Ramsey. Now if $T$ is a $\mathcal{U}$-tree such that $\text{stem}(T)=\langle 0 \rangle$, there cannot exist a pure refinement $T' \subseteq T$ such that $[T'] \subseteq \mathcal{X}'$ or $[T'] \cap \mathcal{X}' = \emptyset$, because there does not exist an $A \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\{\{0\} \cup x \,\, \colon \,\ x \in [A]^\omega \} \subseteq \mathcal{X}'$ or $\{\{0\} \cup x \,\, \colon \,\ x \in [A]^\omega \} \cap \mathcal{X}' = \emptyset$.

Comment: May I know where can I find a text which discusses the fact that $\mathbf{M}_\mathcal{U}$ is dense in $\mathbf{L}_\mathcal{U}$?